# Block upstream jenkins job while downstream is running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I know about the build blocker plugin but doesn't seem to work. Running Jenkins 1.609.

Job A triggers Job B.
I configured Job A to block if job B is running.

If you trigger A and while A is running you trigger A again, once the first A finishes, it triggers B. Then you get both A and B running which shouldn't happen. I guess that when the waiting A checks if B is running, it might be the case that Jenkins is in a middle state where it finished A but not yet really triggered B and therefore we get both of the jobs running.

How can I get this situation to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends if you have a chain of jobs which need to be blocked.
**I can suggest:**

> [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)

Here you can set a regular expression to block certain jobs.
With:

```
.*PART_OF_YOUR_JOB_NAME*
```

You can block every job which matches this string

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, I tried that plugin but it doesn't work as the downstream job starts and the pending upstream job starts at the same time.

Comment: It does work, I have it running like u want it - 
Do you have different slaves in use? then u might need to check "block on global level". Also you should recheck your expression, since a little mistake (as I had) brakes the blocking and you end up in the situation you are discribing...
In JOB A you would see something like this: "(pending—Blocked for 2 hr 13 min by <JobB/C/D>.) Job A stays blocked until the chain finished.

Comment: Beasly, your answer is probably the correct one and it didn't work for me as I might have done some mistake. Now it looks like it's working correctly.

Comment: There seems to be a typo error in your answer. The syntax is .*PART_OF_YOUR_JOB_NAME.* or in case of multiple entries it can be   .*-deploy
  ^maintainance.*

Answer (score 9):

No need to use plugin. I have been using below solutions for a year.

> Job Config --> Advanced Project Options --> Block build when upstream project is building

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work in my case even though it's nice to know about it because I have more than one downstream job and only one of the downstream jobs conflict with the upstream.

Comment: This option blocker for entire downstream job, We would like to setup single downstream job

Comment: For how to do this with Jenkins pipeline, see [How to block upstream/downstream build in Jenkins declarative pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320617/how-to-block-upstream-downstream-build-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)