# How to block upstream/downstream build in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have 3 downstream build jobs which are triggered when 1 upstream job 'Project U' has been built successfully. Example:

```
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
        upstream(upstreamProjects: 'Project U', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }
```

This works as expected, however, if code changes are committed to all parts at the same time, the upstream and downstream builds start building simultaneously.

I want to avoid this, because the downstream builds will run twice, and the first run is quite useless as the upstream commit has not been built yet. So I would like to configure the downstream jobs to block their build while the upstream job is building.

I know how to do this in Jenkins Freestyle job in the user interface (also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753432/4850949)):

[image]

But I cannot find how to do this in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach works:

```
        waitUntil {
            def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Project U")
            !job.isBuilding() && !job.isInQueue()
        }
```

When this downstream is started, it will check if the upstream job is either active or queued, and if so, will wait until its build has finished.

I haven't been able to find out how to programmatically access the current job's upstream job(s), so the job names need to be copied. (There is a method [getBuildingUpstream()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#getBuildingUpstream()), which would be much more convenient, but I haven't found a way to obtain the current Project object from the Job instance.)

I finally ended up creating this function in the Jenkins shared library:

```
/*
    vars/waitForJobs.groovy
    
    Wait until none of the upstream jobs is building or being queued any more

    Parameters:
    
    upstreamProjects   String with a comma separated list of Jenkins jobs to check 
                       (use same format as in upstream trigger) 
    
*/

def call( Map params) {

    projects = params['upstreamProjects'].split(', *')
    
    echo 'Checking the following upstream projects:' 
    if ( projects.size() == 0) {
        echo 'none'
    } else {
        projects.each {project ->
            echo "${project}"
        }
    }
    
    waitUntil {
        def running = false
        projects.each {project ->
            def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(project)
            if (job == null) {
                error "Project '${project} not found"
            }
            if (job.isBuilding()) {
                echo "Waiting for ${project} (executing)"
                running = true             
            }
            if (job.isInQueue()) {
                echo "Waiting for ${project} (queued for execution)"
                running = true
            }
        }
        return !running
    }

}
```

The nice thing is that I can just copy the parameter from the upstream trigger, because it uses the exact same format. Here's an example of how it looks like:

```
pipeline {
[...]   
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
        upstream(upstreamProjects: 'Project U1, Project U2, Project U3', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }    
[...]
    stages {
        stage('Wait') {
            steps {
                script{
                    // Wait for upstream jobs to finish
                    waitForJobs(upstreamProjects: 'Project U1, Project U2, Project U3')
                }
            }
[...]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what would happen if the user has no rights to run the downstream job? I'm currently dealing with this issue. I'm programming post stages to run downstream jobs but I'm afraid any user could add any pipeline

Comment: @Alex Well if the user can't start the downstream job, it won't execute anything including the check for the upstream job. Not sure though if I got your question right?

Comment: You are using declarative pipelines too. What I have seen is that if the user has rights to run the upstream job (simply by clicking the run button) but he has no rights over the downstream job, because the pipelines are run with the SYSTEM user and not the user id, the downstream job gets executed anyway. As we are passing the pipeline job names as a field in the configuration of the upstream pipeline, this is potencially dangerous as a malicious user could add a very very long list of downstream jobs and make the job never end

Comment: I'm aware youa re using the trigger approach from the downstream job to keep a look on the upstream job. In our case we pass pipelines ids to the upstream job to run them in a stage at the end

Comment: @Alex Well then that sounds like a different scenario, probably worth asking a new question.

Comment: I did some days ago, surely. Just in case you got the same error :)